# How to list dates material on order will arrive using Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have a table that has all my different SKU's in item number and shows the dates the product should arrive.  I want to be able to enter the item number and get a list showing when the product will arrive, with the amount.  For example as shown below - I would enter "1022-175" as the Item Number, I want the result to show the following:

1. Jan15 7000
2. Jan22 4005

Here is the table:

| Item Num | Jan1 | Jan8 | Jan15 | Jan22 | Jan29 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1022-158 | 1000 | 5000 |  |  | 6000 |
| 1022-175 |  |  | 7000 | 4005 |  |

I am using Excel 365.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these formulas:

- dates: `INDEX($B$2:$F$3,MATCH($A$6,$A$2:$A$3,0),0)`
- amounts: `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(INDEX($B$2:$F$3,MATCH($A$6,$A$2:$A$3,0),0),INDEX($B$2:$F$3,MATCH($A$6,$A$2:$A$3,0),0)<>""))`

[image]

Comment: Hi Mate, when I use the date formula, it gives me the amounts in columns, not dates.  Also, the information is not in rows like the second formula (which I think can be adressed with the transpose function).

Comment: You can change number format of cells, that'll fix the issue

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked!